# 2 quick WPF (Windows presentation foundation ) questions on tabs and combo boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, binding

I am a very novice WPF programmer, so need help in some simple tasks.

1- As the image shows, I want the (+) tab(it's a tab created with TabItem as of now or should it be button or something else? :-/) to create a tab left to it, say (A1), pressing again, should create (A2), sort of like in tabbed browsers......... And if possible, pressing (-) deletes the selected tab on user prompt.

[alt text http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/4532/tabn.png](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/4532/tabn.png)

2- I want, that user enters text in the textbox, with content separated by comma, or semicolon and that content is added to a COMBOBOX on Button press/click, I guess, it requires some sort of Databinding? Not sure,.. Such that, by the end of it, content from textbox, becomes list within ComboBox (on Button press) ....................
And if possible, the text when selected in text box, on button click(same or different button which was chosen to add textbox content to combobox), it deletes the same from textbox and combobox .

Please help, I am learning WPF, but need this urgent help, which I cannot solve with my current knowledge of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Everything's easier with data binding and MVVM.  Harder at first, but ultimately lots easier.

Make two classes, `Item` and `ItemCollection`, that both implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  `Item` should expose a string `Text` property, while `ItemCollection` should expose an `ObservableCollection<Item>` `Items` property and an `Item` `SelectedItem` property.

Make the `ItemCollection` class's constructor populate `Items` with test data and set `SelectedItem`.

This seems like a lot to do before you actually get around to implementing your tab control, but trust me, you'll like the result.  Your XAML for the TabControl will look something like this:

```
<TabControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <TabControl.DataContext>
        <local:ItemsCollection/>
    </TabControl.DataContext>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <TextBlock Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Let's understand what this does.  It creates a `TabControl`.  It creates an `ItemsCollection` object and sets it as the `TabControl`'s `DataContext`.  You've bound `ItemSource` to `Items`, so the `TabControl` will create a `TabItem` for each item.  It will apply the `ItemContainerStyle` to each `TabItem`, which sets its `Header` property to the `Item`'s  `Text` property.

When the control renders the content of a tab, it finds the item it's rendering, searches through the resources to find a `DataTemplate` whose `DataType` matches the item, and uses that template.  Since we've defined one in `TabControl.Resources`, you get a nice blue background and the `Text` property again.

This seems like a lot to go through.  But now you don't have to write any code that manipulates the UI; you just write code that manipulates your `ItemsCollection`, and the UI pretty much takes care of itself.

Now let's take care of adding new tabs.  What we're going to do is add a new item to the control that, when it becomes selected, adds a new item to the `Items` collection.

Create a new class, called, oh, `ControlItem`.  Have it derive from `Item`.  Modify your `ItemsCollection` constructor so that the last item it adds is a `ControlItem`, not an `Item`.  And have it set the `Text` property on that item to "+".

Add this method to `ItemsCollection`:

```
public Item AddItem()
{
    Item newItem = new Item {Text = "New item"};
    Items.Insert(Items.Count-1, newItem);
    return newItem;
}
```

Now add to your window's code-behind, and as the `SelectionChanged` event handler for your `TabControl`:

```
void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tc = (TabControl) sender;
    if (tc.SelectedItem is ControlItem)
    {
        ItemsCollection ic = (ItemsCollection) tc.DataContext;
        tc.SelectedItem = ic.AddItem();
    }
}
```

You can implement similar logic to remove an item from the list, but you'll need to introduce another variable to `ItemsCollection` to track the previously selected item, so that you can know which item to delete.

Another thing you can do:  implement a `Background` property in `Item` and add a setter to the `ItemContainerStyle` that binds the `TabItem`'s `Background` property to it.  Then you can overload that property in `ControlItem`, so that your add and delete tabs look different.

You can also implement different subclasses for your control items, and have them expose a method that you call in the `SelectionChanged` event handler.  That way, the event handler doesn't have to know anything about what the control item being clicked is doing.  In fact, if you make the method part of `Item`, and have it do nothing unless it's overriden, the window doesn't even need to know that `Item` *has* subclasses.

That's the philosophy behind MVVM in a nutshell:  Bind the view to objects about which it knows almost nothing.  Let the view-model objects control what happens, so that the view doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The tab control should be easy. Handle a Click event on the + tab, create a new tab and make it the active tab. Should be easy... I've gotta run so can't show you the code answer right now. Give it a try and get back with any issues.

The next part I can be a bit more helpful

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtOptions" TextChanged="OnTextChanged"></TextBox>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

the code-behind window (or your class) has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Also set the DataContext property of the window to itself (e.g. in the ctor ) like `this.DataContext = this;`

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       string[] _options;
       public string[] Options
       {
           get
           {  return _options;         }
           set
           {
               _options = value;
               if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                   this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Options"));
           }
       }
```

The text changed event handler modifies the Options property on the code-behind and fires the notification that the property has been modified. The Combobox is notified since it is data bound to that property and self-updates.

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          this.Options = txtOptions.Text.Split(';');
      }
```

Comment: Tragically, the `TabItem` doesn't have a `Click` event.  It doesn't even have a `Selected` event.  It's up to the `TabControl` to respond when the user clicks on a tab.  It also doesn't distinguish between clicking on a tab and navigating to the tab with the keyboard, which is unfortunate if you want those gestures to have different results, as you might in this case.

Comment: Hi Gishu, thanks for help.Though another issue arise, when I tried implementing and found that my ComboBox is not accessible due to reasons mentioned in my next question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302876/datagrid-editable-issue-access-issue-in-wpf .Please help. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Robert - Ah! Didn't know that - Geny, I think you'd have to read up on MVVM (Search for Josh Smith's article on that) to get any non-trivial stuff done easily in WPF